# Specific search in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this phrase in one row in my db:

```
Program: ASYAR10h KITEK10h-pgrp2 Kurs.grp: NDP011-20111-C170V- NDP011-20101-C79V6- Sign: SATB Moment: F2 - Rekursion 1 Aktivitetstyp: Unknown
```

and I just want everything between **Moment:** and **Aktivitetstyp:** to be showed at my webpage. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression

```
// This is where you'll fetch the row out of your 
// database, this is just provided as an example
$mysqlText = 'Program: ASYAR10h KITEK10h-pgrp2 Kurs.grp: NDP011-20111-C170V- NDP011-20101-C79V6- Sign: SATB Moment: F2 - Rekursion 1 Aktivitetstyp: Unknown';

preg_match('/Moment(.*)Aktivitetstyp/', $mysqlText, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicholas!